# UITableViewCell detailTextLabel never displays

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

UITableViewCell detailTextLabel never displays.

*No xib, no storyboard.* I've tried UITableViewCellStyleValue1, UITableViewCellStyleValue2, and UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle. I'm not using subclassed UITableViewCells. I've tried both detailTextLabel.text and detailTextLabel.attributedText. I've verified that the re-use ID isn't used anywhere else and I've stepped through and confirmed that it's the correct value. The textlabel works and so does the accessoryType if I set it. It's just the detailTextLabel that refuses to display.

Notably, the (cell == nil) condition is *never* hit and I have no idea why. I've tried setting the re-use ID to gibberish just to see if it'd have any effect with no success. What have I missed?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:@"reuseCellID"];
    [self setTitle:@"Title"];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *reuseCellID = @"reuseCellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseCellID
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                     reuseIdentifier:reuseCellID];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"detail (one)";
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = self.collection[indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"detail (two)";
    /*NSMutableAttributedString *textLabelStr =
        [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"attributed detail"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.attributedText = textLabelStr;*/

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (cell == nil)` is never hit because you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` and `registerClass: forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

Get rid of the call to `registerClass: forCellReuseIdentifier:` and use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` (without the `forIndexPath:`.

Then your code will do what you expect.

BTW - don't set the `detailTextLabel.text` inside `if (cell == nil)` unless you want every cell to have the same detail text.

Comment: I set detailTextLabel in the cell == nil conditional while debugging. I'll be sure not to set it there. However, if I pull out the call to registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: then I seem to recall the app crashing and telling me I needed to register the cell (but this might have been a previous experiment when I was using a xib).

Comment: That's it. Removing that call as well as forIndexPath: takes care of it. I thought you had to call registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: if you used dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: ...